# Очистка буфера ввода консоли ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер, консоль, ввод

Мне надо ввести размер массива от 1 до 100 и надо сделать проверку корректности ввода, но, когда я ввожу  цифрами букву, то ввод у меня просто зацикливается, я хочу решить проблему очисткой буфера перед следующим вводом, но все равно зацикливается ввод.
Пример кода:

```
input_mas   proc ;      Запрошення для вводу розміру масиву
      S1:invoke     WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR ComSizeMas, Len_ComSize, ADDR nWrite, 0 

      invoke FlushConsoleInputBuffer,h_input
      invoke      crt_scanf,  ADDR format_size_buf, ADDR Size_buf     ; форматний ввід
        CMP Size_buf,1
        JL S1
        CMP Size_buf,100
        JG S1
```

Comment: (Если речь про Windows) можно использовать [`FlushConsoleInputBuffer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/flushconsoleinputbuffer), функция полностью очистит буфер ввода консоли (в том числе и от событий мыши).

Comment: Синтаксис точно такой же как у любой другой WinAPI функции (в зависимости от используемого ассемблера может отличаться). Нужно получить handle ввода, через `invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE`, потом передать этот handle в функцию:  `invoke  FlushConsoleInputBuffer, eax`

Comment: @insolor Расписал мало. У меня при воде данных не того формата, надо очистить буфер ввода и он как и раньше если я вместе с цифрами ввожу буквы зацикливался, так и сейчас

Comment: Тогда распишите вопрос подробнее. То что вы сейчас написали вообще не понятно.

Comment: @insolor Правил по сути